# Where is the syntax error in this python code?

Tags: python, syntax

I'm getting a syntax error on the last line - line 14. I can't see why though, as it seems to be a simple print statement.

```
cel = "c"
far = "f"
cdegrees = 0
fdegrees = 0
temp_system = input ("Convert to Celsius or Fahrenheit?")
if temp_system == cel:
    cdegrees = input ("How many degrees Fahrenheit to convert to Celsius?")
    output = 5/9 * (fdegrees - 32)
    print "That's " + output + " degrees Celsius!"
elif temp_system == far:
    fdegrees = input ("How many degrees Celsius to convert to Fahrenheit?")
    output = (32 - 5/9) / cdegrees
    print "That's " + output + " degrees Fahrenheit!"
else print "I'm not following your banter old chap. Please try again."
```

Comment: Please always include the complete traceback of the error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You forgot the colon (`:`) after the last `else`.

Also:

```
input ("Convert to Celsius or Fahrenheit?")
```

should be changed to

```
raw_input ("Convert to Celsius or Fahrenheit?")
```

as `input()` tries to evaluate its input while `raw_input` takes a 'raw' string. When you enter `c` for example into the `input()` it tries to evaluate the expression `c` as if it were python code which looks for a variable `c` whereas `raw_input` simply takes the string without attempting to evaluate it.

Also you cannot concatenate(add together) strings with integers as you are doing in this case where `output` is a number.

Change it to

```
print "That's " + str(output) + " degrees Celsius!"
```

or

```
print "That's %d degrees Celsius!" % output
```

Comment: Thanks - I didn't realize the : was optional. 
I'm still getting errors in this simple program though. I want to pick celsius so after the first input prompt I enter: c.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'c' is not defined

Didn't I define this at the start?

Comment: Thank you! I've learned about 4 things from this one answer. :)

Comment: No problem. I'm surprised nobody wrote it out before me but everyone just assumed it was the one else statement.